# Can the blockchain be imported into wallets of different brands?

Tags: blockchain, wallet

Can I import the block chain that bitcoin core downloads to use in any of the other full node PC wallets? Are the formats the same or inter-convertible?

Comment: What other full node wallets?

Comment: Any listed (here) https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet under desktop.

Comment: Those aren’t full node wallets. They’re relying on remote services in one way or another.

Comment: The description of half state that 200gb is required and full validation

Comment: Bitcoin Knots

 Bither, msigna

Comment: Knots is a rebrand of Bitcoin core.